# Checking live object record data for decision split in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have built a Journey which injects Salesforce Data from the Opportunity object.

The Journey contains a decision split midway through the Journey to check if a field (Opportunity.Stage) has reached a specific value. I know we can't use Journey Data to check for this, so I've used `Contact Data > (Attribute Group) > Contact > Opportunity > Id` to do this, and compared this to my `Journey Data > Opportunity.Id` and another criteria for `Contact Data > (Attribute Group) > Contact > Opportunity > Stage` = "MY DESIRED STAGE".

I have ran the journey, and after being injected I have made the changes to the Opportunity.Stage before the Decision Split runs 30mins later. However the criteria is never met.

I'm sure this is a common use case and would like to know if this is the correct approach (and what I need to do to correct it) or if there is a better method.